# Twitterハッシュタグの組み合わせを数えるプログラムについて

Tags: python3, google-colaboratory

過去のTwitterの特定のハッシュタグが使用されているツイートデータを収集し、そのハッシュタグが異なるハッシュタグと一緒にツイートされていた場合に、どのような組み合わせで使用されているかをjsonファイルにまとめようとしたのですが、Tweepyを使用してリアルタイムでの収集をすることはできました。
しかし、過去に遡っての収集はAPIを利用したやり方では一週間以上前の収集ができないのでGetOldTweets-pythonというものを利用してツイート自体の収集しましたが、リアルタイムで行っていたプログラムのどこを修正すれば、過去のツイートを収集する場合にも、下記に貼ったリアルタイムで収集していた時の画像と同じような結果の処理を行えるのかがわかりません。

※リアルタイムで収集していたものとハッシュタグが違いますが熱中症で収集したいと思っています。

Tweepyを使用時のプログラム↓

```
from tweepy.streaming 
import StreamListener
import json
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

class MyStreamListener(StreamListener):
def __init__(self, api, **kw):
    self.api = api
    super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()
    self.twcnt = 0

  def on_status(self, tweet):
    self.twcnt += 1
    for tag0, tag1 in itertools.combinations(tweet.entities['hashtags'], 2):
      tag0 = tag0['text']
      tag1 = tag1['text']
      if G.has_edge(tag0, tag1):
        G[tag0][tag1]["weight"] += 1
      else:
        G.add_edge(tag0, tag1, weight=1)

    if self.twcnt > 10000:
      return False

  def on_error(self, status):
    return True

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, MyStreamListener(api))
stream.filter(track=['#RTした人全員フォローする'])
```

GetOldTweetsで過去のツイートを収集するプログラム↓

```
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch('#熱中症').setSince("2018-07-10").setMaxTweets(21000)
tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
print(tweet)
for v in tweet:
    print(v.text)
```

リアルタイムで収集し、ハッシュタグと重複度のみを取り除いたもの↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

GetOldTweetsを使用して過去のハッシュタグ熱中症について収集したもの↓
[image: GetOldTweetsを使用して過去のハッシュタグ熱中症について]

Comment: コードは画像を貼り付けるのでなくて文字列として質問に含めてください．[空白4つで字下げ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) するか， `{ }` のボタンを押せばいい感じに整形できます．

Comment: 申し訳ありません、修正致しました。